# Use external library from controller of symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to use php library in symfony2 Command.
http://phpmidiparser.com/quickstart

I put the library on the same folder of symfony2 but in vain.

```
Command/Midi/bootstrap.php
Command/myCommand.php
```

> ```
> $ php app/console top:myCommand
> ```
>
> syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in error at `use \Midi\Parsing\FileParser;`

```
require_once 'Midi/bootstrap.php';

use \Midi\Parsing\FileParser;
use \Midi\Reporting\TextFormatter;
use \Midi\Reporting\Printer;

$parser = new FileParser();
$parser->load('/path/to/midi/file.mid');

$printer = new Printer(new TextFormatter(), $parser);
$printer->printAll();
```

I use this library only in Command ,so I don't need to register this on autoload.

Please teach me basic guideline of using external library, where should I put the library and how can I 'require'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use`keyword must appear before `require_once` [(http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

```
use \Midi\Parsing\FileParser;
use \Midi\Reporting\TextFormatter;
use \Midi\Reporting\Printer;

require_once 'Midi/bootstrap.php';

$parser = new FileParser();
$parser->load('/path/to/midi/file.mid');

$printer = new Printer(new TextFormatter(), $parser);
$printer->printAll();
```